# gmapping resolution

Tags: ros, navigation, resolution, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a basic question.

Rviz shows a resolution of the map of 0.05.

If I have a (x,y) coordinate of [29, 1983], what is the value in meters of the previous coordinate. I mean [x meters, y meters]

My best guess is that every cell has a value of 0.05, but im not sure

In advance, thank you for your help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66091/gmapping-resolution/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think those coordinates are meters yet.

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
well, it think, it can not be, because I have measured the place and has max of 40-45 meters, and  1983*0.05
ans =  99.150

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
What coordinates are you talking about exactly ?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
But, I may think that every 50 cells is a meter

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
How could that be ? What coordinates are you talking about exactly ? Where did you find them ?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
The coordinates I have mentioned are the coordinates of the empty area of the global map, they have been taken from the  /map topic under gmapping packege. The other issue here is how to relate the initial position of the robot with the origin of the local map.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
I have seen the documentation, and they are 20 cells per meter so it gives a resolution of 0.05. I may have something wrong in the way I get the coordinates from the   /map topic under gmapping packege

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
Well, if you look at here : ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html they say that data from /map topics are given in meters and radians. And they also say in REP 105 that mobile platform's position is relative to the map's frame

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
Thnax for the answer, my issue is how to interpret it.  I have measured the width of the map, 40-45 m, and I get  map.info.width=1984, this means that 1984*0.05= 99.250m, something might be wrong.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
The map.data[i] gives you an array starting from [0,0], and when you make the map based on gmapping, the [0,0] position is where the robot starts. How to make these two origins to coincide.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
If you use turtlebot, there are some files in the turtlebot_navigation/param repository... You might give them a look and edit them. And you can also edit the .yaml which is joined to the map that you use. If not, you might have the equivalent files somewhere.

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2013-09-26**:
can you once check your following parameter values in the gmapping package launch file ?